# NoClassDefFoundError com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-ad-manager

I am from the product team(not an experienced dev) and I am looking to build/run this project in Android Studio. I am researching on different types of google banner Ads and cloned their sample project from [Here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples).

I fixed some of the issues related to AndroidManifest file but ran into other issues when I do a Run. I am sure I am missing some reference or dependency but unable to figure this out alone.

```
 Error:Module 'main6' production: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'm running into the same problem.